# How can I calculate decibel unit (dB) values for PALSAR in GoogleEarthEngine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I use the yearly Palsar mosaic of the GoogleEarthEngine.
In a first step I was able to calculate the HH-HV value and add it as a new Band to my image.
But now I would like to transform in a first step the 16-bit digital numbers (DN) to decibel unit (dB). Therefore, the following equation is provided by the GoogleEarthEngine:

γ₀ = 10log₁₀(DN²) - 83.0 dB

Does anybody know how I can calculate this transformation in the GoogleEarthEngine?

```
var dataset = ee.Image('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR/YEARLY/SAR/2017');

// Compute the HH-HV value and add as new Band
var hhhv = dataset.expression(
  '(HH - HV)', {
    'HH': dataset.select('HH'),
    'HV': dataset.select('HV')
}).rename('HHHV');
var dataset = dataset.addBands(hhhv);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using:

```
// apply: γ₀ = 10log₁₀(DN²) - 83.0 dB
var DN = dataset.select('HHHV');

var dB = DN.pow(2).log10().multiply(10).subtract(83);
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7da68513ea6d3556d219bc3b6eff1680)

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for. However, I changed the formula from .add(83) to .add(-83) to have the right outcome.

Comment: A sorry, I missed that one. Thanks for updating the answer